# Pandas MultiIndexing documentation gives IndexingError

Tags: python, pandas

I am working through the pandas documentation on MultiIndexing at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html.

In the section "Multiindexing using slicers", the below code works as expected.

In [348]:

```
def mklbl(prefix,n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]
```

In [349]:

```
miindex = MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),mklbl('B',2),mklbl('C',4),mklbl('D',2)])
```

In [350]:

```
micolumns = MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),('b','foo'),('b','bah')],names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])
```

However, running "In: [351]",

```
dfmi = DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex)*len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex),len(micolumns))), index=miindex,columns=micolumns).sortlevel().sortlevel(axis=1)
```

followed by

```
dfmi.loc[(slice('A1','A3'),slice(None), ['C1','C3']),:]
```

as per "In [353]" gives an `IndexingError: no slices here`. What is the issue and how can it be resolved?

Comment: are you running 0.14.1?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am running 0.13.1,and not 0.14.1 which only occurred to me after I posted this question. thanks